# AEM 6.5 How to pass content.xml data to react component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, xml, aem

I am very new to AEM 6.5 and React, So basically I am setting up Venia Store view and building a custom component that should be editable as a component `ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/venia/components/sample`, In `sample.html` I am rendering the react component that also working fine but my doubt comes here in sample.html when I give `${properties.ctaText}`the value is rendering fine but the challenge is how to render the same property value inside the react component.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks

**Sample.html**

```
<input type="text" value="${properties.selection}" id="dataSelection" hidden>

<div id="sample"></div>
```

content.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    jcr:title="Tyres"
    sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog">
    <content
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/container">
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <tabs
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/tabs"
                maximized="{Boolean}true">
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <properties
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        jcr:title="Properties"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/container"
                        margin="{Boolean}true">
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <columns
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/fixedcolumns"
                                margin="{Boolean}true">
                                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                    <column
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/container">
                                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                            <tyre-heading
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield"
                                                fieldDescription="tyre heading field"
                                                fieldLabel="Tyre Heading"
                                                name="./selection"
                                                selectionId="combinedSku"/>
                                            <tyreDesc
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield"
                                                fieldDescription="The text displayed by the call-to-action button"
                                                fieldLabel="Call to action text"
                                                name="./ctaText"/>
                                        </items>
                                    </column>
                                </items>
                            </columns>
                        </items>
                    </properties>
                </items>
            </tabs>
        </items>
    </content>
</jcr:root>
```

React:

**Sample.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export default function sample() {
ReactDOM.render(${properties.selection}, document.getElementById('sample'));
};
```

Comment: How doe the model look like? Can you paste a code here?